# I have a swiper refresh layout in home fragment that isn't working

Tags: android, xml, android-studio, kotlin

I have a swiper refresh layout in xml file which is used in the fragment.So, I tried implementing it in the fragment and refreshing the page, but the progress bar is shown indefinitely.

```
 class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

lateinit var recyclerDashboard: RecyclerView

lateinit var layoutManager: RecyclerView.LayoutManager

lateinit var recyclerAdapter: RestaurantRecycleAdapter

lateinit var homeProgress: RelativeLayout

lateinit var searchBar: EditText

lateinit var byName: Chip

lateinit var byNameDesc: Chip

lateinit var byRating: Chip

lateinit var byPrice: Chip

lateinit var byPriceDesc: Chip

lateinit var imageSlider: ImageSlider

lateinit var refreshLayout: SwipeRefreshLayout



val restaurantInfoList = arrayListOf<Restaurant>()



override fun onCreateView(

    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {

    val view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)



    setHasOptionsMenu(true)





    recyclerDashboard = view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerDashboard)

    layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(activity)

    homeProgress = view.findViewById(R.id.progressHomeLayout)

    searchBar = view.findViewById(R.id.main_search_bar)

    imageSlider = view.findViewById(R.id.imageSlider)

    byRating = view.findViewById(R.id.byRating)

    byPrice = view.findViewById(R.id.byPrice)

    byName = view.findViewById(R.id.byName)

    byNameDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.byNameDesc)

    byPriceDesc = view.findViewById(R.id.byPriceDesc)

    refreshLayout = view.findViewById(R.id.refresh)



    val queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(activity as Context)



    val slideModel : ArrayList<SlideModel> = ArrayList()



    slideModel.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.slider1,""))

    slideModel.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.slider2,""))

    slideModel.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.slider3,""))

    slideModel.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.slider4,""))

    slideModel.add(SlideModel(R.drawable.slider1,""))

    imageSlider.setImageList(slideModel)



    val ratingComp = Comparator<Restaurant> { res1, res2 ->

        if (res1.restaurantRating.compareTo(res2.restaurantRating, true) == 0) {
            res1.restaurantName.compareTo(res2.restaurantRating, true)

        } else {

            res1.restaurantRating.compareTo(res2.restaurantRating, true)

        }



    }
    fetchCode(queue)


    searchBar.addTextChangedListener(object : TextWatcher {
        override fun afterTextChanged(p0: Editable?) {
        }
        override fun beforeTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {
        }
        override fun onTextChanged(p0: CharSequence?, p1: Int, p2: Int, p3: Int) {

            val listData = arrayListOf<Restaurant>()
            for (i in 0 until restaurantInfoList.size) {
                if (restaurantInfoList[i].restaurantName.toLowerCase()
                        .contains(searchBar.text.toString().toLowerCase()) ||
                    restaurantInfoList[i].restaurantPrice.contains(searchBar.text.toString()) ||
                    restaurantInfoList[i].restaurantRating.contains(searchBar.text.toString())
                ) {
                    listData.add(restaurantInfoList[i])
                }
            }
            recyclerDashboard.adapter = RestaurantRecycleAdapter(activity as Context, listData)
            (recyclerDashboard.adapter as RestaurantRecycleAdapter).notifyDataSetChanged()
        }


    }
    )

    refreshLayout.setOnRefreshListener{
        fetchCode(queue)
        refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false

    }



    val costComparator = Comparator<Restaurant> { rest1, rest2 ->

        rest1.restaurantPrice.compareTo(rest2.restaurantPrice, true)
    }
    val ratingCompName = Comparator<Restaurant> { item1, item2 ->
        if (item1.restaurantName.compareTo(item2.restaurantName, true) == 0) {
            item1.restaurantName.compareTo(item2.restaurantName, true)



        } else {



            item1.restaurantName.compareTo(item2.restaurantName, true)



        }



    }
    byPrice.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(restaurantInfoList, costComparator)
        restaurantInfoList.reverse()

        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
    byPriceDesc.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(restaurantInfoList, costComparator)
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
    byRating.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(restaurantInfoList, ratingComp)
        restaurantInfoList.reverse()

        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
    byName.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(restaurantInfoList, ratingCompName)
        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }
    byNameDesc.setOnClickListener {
        Collections.sort(restaurantInfoList, ratingCompName)
        restaurantInfoList.reverse()

        recyclerAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged()

    }


    return view
}

private fun fetchCode(queue: RequestQueue)
{

    val url = "http://13.235.250.119/v2/restaurants/fetch_result/"
    if (ConnectionManager().checkConnectivity(activity as Context)) {
        homeProgress.visibility = View.INVISIBLE
        val jsonObjectRequest =
            object : JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url, null, Response.Listener {
                try {
                    val response = it.getJSONObject("data")
                    val success = response.getBoolean("success")

                    if (success) {
                        val data = response.getJSONArray("data")
                        for (i in 0 until data.length()) {
                            val restaurantJsonObject = data.getJSONObject(i)
                            val restaurantObject = Restaurant(
                                restaurantJsonObject.getString("id"),
                                restaurantJsonObject.getString("name"),
                                restaurantJsonObject.getString("rating"),
                                restaurantJsonObject.getString("cost_for_one"),
                                restaurantJsonObject.getString("image_url")
                            )

                            restaurantInfoList.add(restaurantObject)
                            recyclerAdapter = RestaurantRecycleAdapter(
                                activity as Context,
                                restaurantInfoList
                            )

                            recyclerDashboard.adapter = recyclerAdapter
                            recyclerDashboard.layoutManager = layoutManager

                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            activity as Context,
                            "Some Error",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }

                } catch (e: Exception) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                }

            }, Response.ErrorListener {
                if (activity != null) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity as Context, "Volley Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                        .show()
                }
            }) {
                override fun getHeaders(): MutableMap<String, String> {
                    val headers = HashMap<String, String>()
                    headers["Content-type"] = "application/json"
                    headers["token"] = "9bf534118365f1"
                    return headers
                }

            }
        queue.add(jsonObjectRequest)
    } else {
        val dialog = AlertDialog.Builder(activity as Context)
        dialog.setTitle("ERROR")
        dialog.setMessage("Internet Connection  Not Found")
        dialog.setPositiveButton("Open Settings") { text, listener ->
            val settingsIntent = Intent(Settings.ACTION_WIRELESS_SETTINGS)
            startActivity(settingsIntent)
            activity?.finish()

        }

        dialog.setNegativeButton("Exit") { text, listener ->
            ActivityCompat.finishAffinity(activity as Activity)
        }
        dialog.create()
        dialog.show()
    }
}
```

}

R.id.refresh is the id of the swiper refresh layout and HomeFragment is the name of the fragment that it is used in.

I posted the entire code, where the fetching of data is in a function and that particular function is called in refreshing. But the page isn't refreshing at all.

Comment: The loaded won't go away until you explicitly call ``refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false``. Also, I think you are using it for the wrong purpose.

Comment: Why is that wrong purpose? I have a swiper refresh layout, so when I refresh the page has to reload. If Im doing it wrong then how should I do it properly ??@BilalNaeem

Comment: Instead of reloading the entire fragment, you should instead call those specific methods that load the data in your view. After those methods have been called, you can tell the swipe refresh layout that it is done refreshing.

Comment: I have edited it like u said. Is this correct ?

Comment: This is correct. However, you should move your ``refreshLayout.isRefreshing = false`` to run after your ``fetchCode()`` method runs (since it is asynchronous the loader will instantly disappear even if the ``fetchCode()`` method has not completed)

Comment: It is refreshing, but isnt refreshing properly, the list gets collapsed

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/234771/discussion-between-yazhini-and-bilal-naeem).